# CORS issue in Next.js 14 Server Actions with Third-Party API calls

Tags: next.js, cors, resend.com

I'm trying to use the Resend API to create a simple contact form in NextJS. To do this, I created a server action to connect to the API and send the email. When run the code, I get the following CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.resend.com/emails' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Here's my `sendEmail` function in /app/_actions.ts:

```
export async function sendEmail({email, name, org, message}: {email: string, name: string, org?: string, message?: string}){
    const resend = new Resend(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RESEND_API_KEY);
    const myEmail = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL || '';

    try {
        const data = await resend.emails.send({
            from: myEmail,
            to: myEmail,
            subject: `${name}, from ${org}`,
            html: `${email}: ${message}`
          });    
        return { success: true , data };
    } catch(error) {
        return { success: false , error };
        }
    }
```

And here's the code in my .tsx component that calls this action:

```
const submitEmail = async ({email, name, org, message}: {email: string, name: string, org: string, message: string}) => {
        const result = await sendEmail({email, name, org, message})
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })
}
```

I've found that I may have to modify my `next.config.ts` file, but I wasn't able to find anything that worked.

I would greatly appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After reading [Resend How do I fix CORS issues?](https://resend.com/docs/knowledge-base/how-do-i-fix-cors-issues),
I found that all I had to do was add `"use server";` in the beginning of my `/app/_actions.ts` file.